# 80s SF/F movie with exotic cult, soldier of fortune

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

So, I was flipping through broadcast last night, and I caught just a couple of brief glimpses of a B action flick on a lesser channel.

I would guess it to be 80s/90s in time period. The protagonist seemed to be a hard-bitten, modern soldier-of-fortune in a beret --he looked like Dolph Lundgren, but I'm not sure it was him. In one scene he shares a cigarette with a young man of indeterminate "exotic" origin.

In another scene, he and a character who looked like John Denver, and whom I'm just going to guess was an archaeologist, were held prisoner by some vaguely Egyptian-looking guards with spears that shot out energy bolts, in front of an androgynous young ruler/cult-leader, and a retinue of boy priests. There was some kind of tussle, and everyone got zapped with the energy spears. Then the ruler's eyes started glowing.

That's all I saw of it --can anyone identify it?

Comment: You're fine to leave incorrect information in the question, in fact it's preferable in case others have made the same mistake.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - OK, but you've got to protect me from being beaten up by irate *Stargate* fans...

Comment: I missed any related comments that may have precipitated the deletion of ones that I made. For my part, if you mistook my (intended) good-natured kidding as that of an irate fan being rude, I sincerely apologize! That was not my intention at all

Comment: @NKCampbell I was just joking as well! :)  I had tried to edit out my reference to "Stargate" as a B-movie, but TLC convinced me to keep it as is.  // Anyway, apparently what I need to worry about is not being beaten up, but being exiled to a distant, Egyptian-themed planet.

Comment: "he looked like Dolph Lundgren" lolz

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Since we don't seem to have a high-quality answer for this, I'm going to post that this is almost certainly the 1994 movie [*Stargate*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111282/).  After an alien ring is discovered in the desert, it is activated to reach a distant alien (also desert) world, where conflict arises when the alien rulers return.

The movie has a strong Egyptian aesthetic; the gate is discovered in Egypt, the alien and its retinue favour Egyptian themes (and may be the originators of them on Earth) and even the pyramids are explained as the landing pads for the alien spaceships.

As for the scenes you remember, here are Kurt Russell (in a beret) and James Spader:

[image]

Here is Ra (centre, in helmet), some of his retinue, and his guards (wearing their helmets, armed with energy staves):

[image]

The young man of "indeterminate origin" is named Skaara and took to the Earth soldiers and was partly accepted by them:

[image]

The alien Ra does have an androgynous appearance:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This was definite. What's funny is I was going to say the ruler looked like the actor who plays the transgender character in "The Crying Game." But I had no idea it actually was that actor.

Comment: Stargate was certainly not a B movie when released -  it was box office premier. It's still considered a good movie today

Comment: Not to mention spawning 16 seasons of live-action TV, and a bunch of animation (I think)

Comment: @JozefWoods Not to mention further... 3-4 successful spin-offs and defining numerous tropes to be imitated by mainstream sci-fi later and through that garner quite the cult following.

Comment: Honestly, I think the spin-offs gained far more cultural relevancy than the original movie, but it looks like it *did* at one time hold the record for box-office in an October release, which isn't nothing.

Comment: Well it _was_ an [Roland Emmerich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roland_Emmerich) movie. Go in theater, switch off brain, be above the plot sillyness and lack of logic, enjoy the action.

Comment: First use of a Quantel Domino in a major film (after the practical effect failed)